# range in an array

Tags: ruby, range

I cannot seem to iterate through a range. Here is what I get:

```
[1..6].to_a.each{ |n|
  puts(n)
}
# => [1..6]
```

This is one iteration without offering each number. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 7):

`[1..6]` does not define a range. It defines an array with one element that is a range:

```
[1..6] == (1..6)
# => false
[1..6].class
# => Array

[1..6] == [(1..6)]
# => true
[1..6][0].class
# => Range
```

The correct syntax to create a range is `(1..6)`:

```
(1..6).each { |n| puts n }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
6.times { |n| puts n }
```

if u want to iterate n times

Answer (score 1):

Your one is not working, as you created *an array of range* of **size 1**. Now, to make it working you can do as :

```
[*1..3].each { |n| puts n }
```

It would output as :

```
1
2
3
```

But better in such case, to use

```
(1..3).each { |n| puts n }
```

As `Range` is an *enumerable*, you can call on it the [`Range#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html#method-i-each) method.